# match mutiple patterns using awk command

Tags: linux, awk

My file looks like

```
10.183.227.46|242066391737|73633662;244809|com.com|com.com|2001|CCA-I|0|[29/Dec/2016:00:00:40]|26|RULE_31893406,RULE_31893405,RULE_416241598|4106,4105,4000|2006,2005,5000|0|0|0|0|2621440|3000|-|-|1003:0,1013:0,1010:Home|244809|0|117,115,40|-|-|
```

I want to see files which contains `117` in 24th field and `2001` in 6th field

I am using

```
awk -F "|" '{if($6==2001 && $24==117)print }' 29_DEC_2016.1
```

but as 24th field can contain more than 1 value seperated by comma
I am not getting the correct result

Comment: Does the `117` have to be at the start of the 24th field or can it be any any position and still match, e.g. should `115,117,40` match?

Comment: it can be at any position

Comment: Then the answer you have accepted does not work for you as the first script will only look at the first position while the second script will find false matches in any position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use `GNU awk`, `split` function on the column with `,` de-limiter to extract the words and do a check on that value

```
awk -F "|" '{split($25,array1,","); if ( $6 == "2001" && array1[1] == "117" ){print} }' file
```

If the element can occur anywhere in the column, just a `~` regex match would be sufficient.

```
awk -F "|" '$6 == "2001" && $25 ~ /117/' file
```

Refer this [James Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41442428/5291015) for even more rigorous regEx match.

Comment: it is not necessary that 117 will be first number

Comment: @Prafull: Refer my update which should solve your problem

Comment: That `$25` need some work, it fails if there's for example `1117` in it. I ran out of time testing it for now. ++

Comment: @JamesBrown: Thought of the same, thinking to use `length`, may be you have a better idea, feel free to update a new answer or mine

Comment: @Inian See my solution, that's the best I could come up with for now.

Comment: There's nothing gawk-specific about that answer, it'd behave the same in any awk. The 2nd script is wrong as it'll produce a false match if`123117456` for example exists in that field.

Comment: @EdMorton: Agree Ed! Thats why provided a direct reference to James' answer

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F\| '$6=="2001" && $25 ~ /(^|,)117($|,)/' file
```

`$6` equals `"2001"` (do not use just `2001` because in case you were searching for `0`, `$6==0` would fail the implicit print) and `$25` includes exactly `117` (preceeded and followed by *start-of-string* `^` or (`|`) *end-of-string* or comma `,` (you could throw in space just in case)).

Testing the latter part:

```
$ cat foo
117,2,3   # good
1,117,3   # good
1,2,117   # good
1117,2,3  # bad
1,1117,3  # bad
1,2,1177  # bad
$ awk '$1~/(^|,)117($|,)/' foo
117,2,3   # good
1,117,3   # good
1,2,117   # good
```

Comment: `++` for the regEx only

Comment: Included a reference to your answer in mine !

Comment: `/[,^]/` don't "work" because `[]` is a bracket expression within which characters are treated literally (with a few position-based exceptions) so `^` in `[,^]` is a literal `^` character, not the regexp start-of-string character. Similarly for `$`. What you did with `(^|,)` is the correct syntax for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JamesBrown- very nice information and command sir, thank you for sharing the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[|,]' '{print $6,$(NF-5)}'  file

2001 117
```